# Prove that $(d (a + e) + b (c + e) + (a + c) f)^2 - 4 (a c + a e + c e) (b d + b f + d f)$ cannot be factored as a square

Tags: polynomials, radicals

For understanding of the question let's start with two examples:

We can factor $V(a,b,c)=a^4 + 2 a^2 b + b^2 - 2 a^2 c - 2 b c + c^2$ as a square, i.e we can write $V$ as square of a function $p(a,b,c)=a^2 + b - c$ so that holds $V=p^2$. Another example is $W(a,b)=a^2 + 2 a b + 2 a^{3/2} b + b^2 + 2b^2 \sqrt a  + a b^2$ that can be factored as $W=r^2$ with $r(a,b)=a + b\sqrt a  + b$.

The problem:

The function of interest is
$U(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(d (a + e) + b (c + e) + (a + c) f)^2 - 4 (a c + a e + c e) (b d + b f + d f)$

with $(a,b,c,d,e,f)\in \mathbb{R}$. The aim is to take the square root of $U$. Therefore I tried to factor $U$ as a square, but failed, i.e. could not find the function $q(a,b,c,d,e,f)\in \mathbb C$ with $U=q^2$. How to prove that factorization is (not) possible? For factorization I consider for $q$ any mathematical function.

Comment: Since $U\in \Bbb Z[a,b,c,d,e,f]$, it is enough to find integer values for the variables, so that the value of $U$ is not a square. So it can't be a square.

Comment: You should specify what you mean by "another term". @DietrichBurde showed that if $U = q^2$, then $q$ cannot be a polynomial with integer coefficients. On the other extreme, if $U$ is positive on your domain, you can certainly take $q = \sqrt{U}$, so that $U = q^2$.

Comment: @granularbastard "*excluding the trivial solutions* $q=\pm\sqrt{U}\,$" $\;$ This makes no sense. Any solution to $q^2 = U$ will be equal to $\pm\sqrt{U}$ *as a function*. It doesn't matter whether you write it as $q = \sqrt{U}$ or $q = e^{\ln(x) / 2}$ or whatever other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We can factor $V(a,b,c)=a^4 + 2 a^2 b + b^2 - 2 a^2 c - 2 b c + c^2$ as a square

Considering it as a polynomial $P(a)$ in $a$ with coefficients parameterized in $b,c$, the condition for a multiple root is for $\gcd(P(a), P'(a))$ to have degree $\ge 1$. Calculating the [polynomial $\gcd$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_algorithm) gives (verified by [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gcd%28+a%5E4+%2B+2+a%5E2+b+%2B+b%5E2+-+2+a%5E2+c+-+2+b+c+%2B+c%5E2%2C+4+a%5E3+%2B+4+a+b+-+4+a+c+%29)):

$$
\gcd(a^4 + 2 a^2 b + b^2 - 2 a^2 c - 2 b c + c^2, 4 a^3 + 4 a b - 4 a c) = a^2 + b - c
$$

Therefore $(a^2 + b - c)^2 \,|\, P(a)$, and in fact $(a^2 + b - c)^2 \,=\, P(a)\,$ by degree considerations.

> $U(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(d (a + e) + b (c + e) + (a + c) f)^2 - 4 (a c + a e + c e) (b d + b f + d f)$

Considering it as a polynomial $Q(a)$ in $a$, it can be verified that $\gcd(Q(a), Q'(a)) = 1$ ([WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gcd%28+%28d+%28a+%2B+e%29+%2B+b+%28c+%2B+e%29+%2B+%28a+%2B+c%29+f%29%5E2+-+4+%28a+c+%2B+a+e+%2B+c+e%29+%28b+d+%2B+b+f+%2B+d+f%29%2C+2+%28d+%2B+f%29+%28d+%28a+%2B+e%29+%2B+b+%28c+%2B+e%29+%2B+%28a+%2B+c%29+f%29+-+4+%28c+%2B+e%29+%29)) so $Q(a)$ has no polynomial factor at a power greater than $1$, which implies that it is not the square of another polynomial.

Comment: The OP says:"For factorization I consider for $q$ any mathematical function." So not only a polynomial. But it seems OK, since he/she accepts the answer nevertheless.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know, and I notice the OP hasn't replied to my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4660981/prove-that-d-a-e-b-c-e-a-c-f2-4-a-c-a-e-c-e-b-d-b/4661187?noredirect=1#comment9846693_4660981) under the main post ;-)

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$
U(1,-2,1,3,1,0)=76,
$$
which is not a square in $\Bbb Z$. Suppose that $U\in \Bbb Z[a,b,c,d,e,f]$ is a square, i.e., $$U(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(p(a,b,c,d,e,f)^2$$
for some polynomial $p\in \Bbb Z[a,b,c,d,e,f]$ - this is meant by a *factorization*. Then every integer value of $U$ needs to be a square in $\Bbb Z$. This is not true, as $76$ is not a square.

On the other hand, $V=a^4 + 2 a^2 b + b^2 - 2 a^2 c - 2 b c + c^2$ is a square of a polynomial $p\in \Bbb Z[a,b,c]$, namely $p(a,b,c)=a^2+b-c$. And
all integer values for $V$ are indeed squares.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144703/discussion-on-answer-by-dietrich-burde-prove-that-d-a-e-b-c-e-a); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider $U$ as a function $\mathbb R^6 \to \mathbb R$, then it is a square of another function $q: \mathbb R^6 \to \mathbb C$. Note that we need complex numbers in the codomain here, but cannot also take them in the domain! Define $q$ by
$$q(a,b,c,d,e,f) = \begin{cases} \sqrt{U(a,b,c,d,e,f)} & \text{if} & U(a,b,c,d,e,f) > 0 \\ i \sqrt{-U(a,b,c,d,e,f)} & \text{if} & U(a,b,c,d,e,f) < 0\end{cases}$$
where $i \in \mathbb C$ is the imaginary unit. Then clearly
$$q(a,b,c,d,e,f)^2 = U(a,b,c,d,e,f)$$
for all $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb R$.